# Performance difference from putting function outside of React component?

Tags: reactjs

I know that it's going to be small, but is there a performance difference if you put functions outside of a React component?

Eg version 1:

```
const handleFetch = () => {
    // Make API call
}

const MyComponent = () => {
    useEffect(()=>{
        handleFetch();
    })
    return(<p>hi</p>)
}
```

Vs version 2:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
    const handleFetch = () => {
        // Make API call
    }

    useEffect(()=>{
        handleFetch();
    })
    return(<p>hi</p>)
}
```

In version 1 would `handleFetch` not be recreated when `MyComponent` re-renders?

Comment: Wonder if placing a breakpoint over handleFetch would tell if a method is newly reassigned or not?

Comment: Only in v2, `handleFetch` will be recreated when `MyComponent` re-renders. Another note: `useCallback` will not avoid recreating functions (you still pass a new function into `useCallback` too).

Comment: It's not worth the minute performance difference for the loss of readability and scoping. Only put the function outside the component if it logically belongs there because it's a general-purpose utility or is shared among components (it should likely be in another module). If you're experiencing a slow app, profile it and look for the real problem--this sort of desperate micro-maneuver isn't going to fix it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> is there a performance difference if you put functions outside of a React component?

Yes but you will likely never run into a noticeable performance downgrade of deciding to define a function inside a component. Almost always, the rest of your application's performance will overshadow the cost of putting functions in your components. Quoted from React's FAQ regarding functions defined in functional components in general:

> Are Hooks slow because of creating functions in render?
>
> No. In modern browsers, the raw performance of closures compared to classes doesn’t differ significantly except in extreme scenarios.

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#are-hooks-slow-because-of-creating-functions-in-render

> In version 1 would handleFetch not be recreated when MyComponent re-renders?

No, it will not be recreated because `handleFetch` is defined outside of the functional component. It's only in version 2 `handleFetch` will be recreated when MyComponent re-renders.

Another note: useCallback will not avoid recreating functions (you still pass a new function into useCallback too).

As a general rule for me, define the function inside the component first then extract it if it's not a hassle or it can be reused among multiple components. Sometimes, when I do extract it, I find I need to add 2 or more extra parameters to pass variables from my component to the function. But if I left it inside the functional component, I wouldn't need any parameters.

Answer (score 2):

The approved answer isn't fully correct. There is one really important distinction about this sentence:

> Another note: useCallback will not avoid recreating functions (you still pass a new function into useCallback too).

The function you pass to useCallback **is** returned every render. This means you have the **same** function, assuming the dependencies you defined haven't changed.

As an exercise to the reader define a function inside of a useCallback and store that result into a variable and then in a useEffect have that variable be the sole dependency. The useEffect will not re-run bc it's the same reference (strict equality.)

Comment: No need for the exercise. The behavior is well documented in the docs