# is it ok to do this in react, to put the event handlers and other functions that depend on useState outside the component

Tags: reactjs

is it okay to do this in react, to put the event handlers and other functions that depend on useState outside the component? to avoid wrapping my functions in useCallback

like with this example:

```
import { useState } from "react";

const handleClick = (fn) => fn((prev) => prev + 1);

export default function App() {
  const [val, setVal] = useState(0);

  return (
    <>
      <p onClick={() => handleClick(setVal)}>clicked {val}</p>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Why not `() => setVal(prev => prev + 1)`? Why introduce the middle man `handleClick` thereby introducing more closures and under performing code.

Comment: it's just an example, the event handler can be more than 1 line of code

Comment: There are lots of questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60660415/performance-difference-from-putting-function-outside-of-react-component, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62848106/functional-component-write-functions-inside-or-outside-the-component, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73244234/react-event-handlers-inside-or-outside-functional-component

Comment: What do you mean "is it OK"? Have you tried it? Does it work?

Comment: @LinDu Looks like you could dupehammer it?

Comment: @TylerH, yes it works, but I was just asking if it's OK to do it in that style or is it against React's recommendations because it may cause problems down the line

Comment: @GabtniMohamed React is a language, it doesn't have recommendations. Code written in it either works or it doesn't.

Comment: @TylerH it is a javascript library

Comment: @GabtniMohamed Sure, potato potato. Libraries don't tell you how to write things. Frameworks _start to_, but you still have a lot of freedom. The only time where there is a 'right' or 'wrong' way to do something where multiple ways work is when you have a specific style guide (like PEP8 in Python) that dictates exactly how you should write code.

Answer (score 1):

[Since React optimizes the re-render process by memoizing function references, you are implicitly using memoization. <sup>[wikipedia]</sup>](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization)

> it's just an example, the event handler can be more than 1 line of code

As long as the function stays pure and stateless, it will not be recreated upon each re-render.

---

You can even export it from a separate module and then import the pure stateless functions you want to make use of.

Answer (score -1):

The useCallback hook ensures that handleClick is memoized and won't be recreated on every render unless its dependencies change.

```
import React, { useState, useCallback } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [val, setVal] = useState(0);

  const handleClick = useCallback(() => {
    setVal((prev) => prev + 1);
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <p onClick={handleClick}>clicked {val}</p>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: I know this, it is just that you need to wrap the function in useCallback if it is inside the component, because for example if the function is passed down to a child it can cause the unnecessary re-rendering of the child

Comment: then using useCallback can be a good solution, I have updated my code check it once.

Comment: *”to avoid wrapping my functions in useCallback”* the OP explicitly speaks against `useCallback`.